# how to add an admin in laravel 5.1 auth manually from database

Tags: php, laravel

any body has any idea how to pass the authentication of laravel ? or to add an admin from database or the source code ? assuming you have created an admin panel and an admin user but you lost your database and now you just want to create a new admin user for your panel . i used default laravel authentication and middle ware for admin panel . here is the middle ware added in kernel.php

```
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthAdmin::class,
```

and here we got role controller

```
 if(Auth::user()->isSuperAdmin()) {
        $objects = Role::select($this->dt_fields_db)->where('id','<>',1)->where('id','<>',3);
    } else {
        $objects = Role::select($this->dt_fields_db)->where('id','>',3);
    }
```

Comment: cant find it in web can any one tell me what '<>' means in the above controller code ?

Comment: `<>` means not equal to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a new Seeder class, create a user and the super admin role, assign the role to the user and be a super admin forever and ever.

```
public class SuperAdminSeeder {
    public function run () {
        // modify to following commands fit your table structure
        $role = Role::create(['name' => 'super_admin'];
        $user = User::create(['email' => 'your@email.com', 'password' => bcrypt('secret')]);
        DB::table('role_user')->insert(['user_id' => $user->id, 'role_id' => $role->id]);
    }
}
```

Call it via the command line:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=SuperAdminSeeder::class
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run php `artisan make:auth` and  `php artisan migrate`. Then, navigate your browser to  `http://your-app.dev/register` or any other URL that is assigned to your application. These two commands will take care of scaffolding your entire authentication system.

Comment: my laravel is 5.1 and unfortunately this version dont support the make:auth command for that i have to update it which this damage my application